# mailing list manager (on Debian VPS) compatible with HTML5 emails

Tags: linux

For the [RefPerSys](https://refpersys.org/) project, we need an open source mailing list manager (running on a cheap VPS rented server `ovh.starynkevitch.net` under Debian whose web server is [lighttpd](https://lighttpd.org/), so FastCGI compatible).

I expect the mail traffic to stay small (a dozen of emails, each less than 20Kbytes of HTML, each day). I do know that the Web traffic is small also ([refpersys.org](https://refpersys.org/) gets just a hundred HTTP requests per day).

We absolutely need that list to be publicly visible on the web, and we really use HTML emails, not plain text ones. AFAIK, this rules out both [mailman](https://list.org/) and [sympa](https://sympa.org/). And I am not familiar with Python or Perl (even if I did learn many programming languages and even developed [GCC MELT](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt/), a Lispy dialect to extend GCC in the past).

A typical email on that list would be [refpersys.org/refpersys-Qt-based-GUI-mail-2019dec19.html](http://refpersys.org/refpersys-Qt-based-GUI-mail-2019dec19.html); I extracted that manually from the thunderbird `*.eml` file.

I am capable of compiling a mailing list server program coded in C++, Go, C, ... etc. But even [listmonk](https://listmonk.app/) does not seem to accept HTML5 messages.

I could develop one myself in C++ (using [Vmime](https://vmime.org/) + [myhtml](https://github.com/lexborisov/myhtml) + some FastCGI library) or Go (improving [nanolist](https://github.com/eXeC64/nanolist) or listmonk) perhaps  under GPLv3+ license, but that would take me a week or two. I prefer devoting that time to RefPerSys.

Do you know other open source mailing list manager software compatible with HTML5 emails, e.g. Guile based? I am quite familiar with Guile.

I am very reluctant to use Google Groups, because several academics which could be interested by RefPerSys are hostile to Google (and as a French citizen and free software activist member of [April](https://www.april.org/), I tend to understand their position)

I could use [framalistes.org/sympa](https://framalistes.org/sympa) (I regularly donate a few dozen of euros to them) but sympa is not friendly with HTML5 emails.

I care a lot about cybersecurity, since by day I am supposed to be a cybersecurity expert (since professionally developing tools like [bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/))

Answer (score 1):

Despite your concerns, I'm pretty sure that mailman can do what you want.

And I just did a quick google and [this (somewhat ironically plain text) message](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/mailman-users/2018-February/083068.html) (from the mailman-users mailing list) and it's responses suggests it's possible?!